# How to open a new browser tab or window and perform operations on that newly opened page using Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to do a simple Robot-test to demonstrate opening multiple tabs or browser windows with Robot Framework. After getting this simple example to work I could use this code to open multible tabs or windows on longer tests.

The idea is this:
Browser is opened to www.google.com and Text1 is inputted to google search-bar.
Then another tab (or window) is opened to google.com as well on this simple example as second page and Text2 is inputted instead there as text. Opening second instance of google page currently works but problem is that Text2 gets inputted to original page's search bar and not in the newly opened one. Both tab or window would be good options to use later I think but problem now is that inputting is done to original page after that second one is succesfully opened. I think that new window or tab should be selected somehow and not sure if JavaScript is correct way to open that second one as I have done here?

My current robot code:

```
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
multipletabstest
    Open Browser    http://www.google.com    Chrome
    Input Text      xpath://input[@name="q"]    Text
    Comment         Open second google-tab
    Execute Javascript    window.open('https://www.google.com');
    Input Text      xpath://input[@name="q"]    Text2
```

Comment: Why are you using javascript to open the second window instead of calling `Open browser` a second time?

Comment: Possile duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682332/robot-framework-chrome-new-tab-issue/53705342#53705342

Answer (score 0):

I think I actually tried calling Open browser yesterday but somehow did not get it to work with that text inputting behaviour as expected. Now that I tested it again (replacing JavaScript line with Open Browser) that worked so thanks! Before logging in here I came with another solution. That code is longer but I think I currenty prefer how this opens new tabs with Chrome (although code for example window.open() refers to windows) to the top of browser. With Firefox this seems to open as new windows. Both are usable for me though as main idea would be to be able to open multiple instances of same page and I think there could be many solutions. This is probably kind of over commented but comments are here just for clarification what this solution does. I found a base for this on SeleniumLibrary documentation page. There was different sites used for each window but I tested this with multiple google pages.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
multipletabstest
    Comment         Open first google window
    Open Browser    https://www.google.com      Chrome
    Input Text      xpath://input[@name="q"]    Text to first window
    Comment         Open second window
    Execute Javascript    window.open('https://www.google.com')
    Comment         Change to new window
    Switch Window   locator=NEW      
    Comment         Input text to second window
    Input Text      xpath://input[@name="q"]    Text to second window
    Comment         Open third window
    Execute Javascript    window.open('https://www.google.com')
    Comment         Change to new window
    Switch Window   locator=NEW
    Comment         Input text to third window
    Input Text      xpath://input[@name="q"]    Text to third window
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use FOR loop;

```
*** Variables ***
${url}       https://www.google.com
${search}    xpath://input[@name="q"]


*** Tasks ***   
Multiple windows TEST
    ${urls_list}=    Create List    ${url}    ${url}
    FOR    ${url}    IN    @{urls_list} 
        Open Browser    ${url}
        Input Text      ${search}    Text
    END
```